# Delete a variable piece of text from every line in textfile

Tags: replace, find

I have a .txt file full with lines like:

```
username:password:*email*:email_address, where *email* is a fixed word throughout the file.
```

I wanted to delete everything after the first **:** and before the second **:**, in other words, delete the passwords and have only `username:*email*:email_address`.

Can anyone help me? Thanks

Comment: Using what?  Some programming language, some application/utility?

Comment: Anything. I would like some help to determine the easiest way to do this. Tried with notepad ++ but couldn't seem to find a way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write a Python script like this:

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        fields = line.split(':')
        del fields[1]
        print ':'.join(fields),
```

and redirect the output to a new file.